# How to release heap memory in android

Tags: java, android

I want to develop a list view which contains an image and a text view this code done it
  perfectly but my code allocating lot of heap memory it doesn't releasing the memory.
  I initialized all nulls in ondestroy but it does nothing for me.

Help me any one i am stuck with this......

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private ListView mListview;
private EventsAdapter adapter;
InitialRequestResponseDto mInitialRequestResponseDto;
Context mContext;
private ImageButton mPlayButton;
//private ImageButton mRepeatButton;
private ImageButton mNextButton;
private ImageButton mPreviousButton;
//private ImageButton mStopButton;
TextView title, descrip;
ImageView songIcon;
boolean mBroadcastIsRegistered;
Intent intent, serIntent;
static ProgressDialog mdialog;
LazyImageLoader lazyImageLoader;
private static int songEnded = 0;
private TextView mHeading;
final String SUGGESTED_URL = "http://www.vorbis.com/music/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg";
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
private ImageButton mHome;
private ImageButton mFm;
private String langid;
private ImageView mArrow;
Typeface tf,tf2;
private Button mBack;
String mRprgmname;
private TextView mPrgmTxtVw;
private TextView mPrgmName;

private RelativeLayout mrelative;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.commonsongslist);
    mrelative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Rlplayall);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songnamemaint);
    songIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cntrylogo);
    mPrgmTxtVw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prmnametxt);
    mPrgmName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prmname);
    mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backs);
    mHome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.commonlayout);
    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(234, 183, 51));
    mListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listsongs);
    mHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtheading);
    mPlayButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextbtn);
    mPreviousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prvsbtn);
    mArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrowimage);
    mArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.events_a);
    mFm = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fmbtn);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    langid = intent.getStringExtra("languageid");
    lazyImageLoader = new LazyImageLoader(mContext);
    mHeading.setText("Events");
    DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    // mHeading.setTextSize(20/ metrics.scaledDensity);
    if (metrics.scaledDensity < 1) {
        mHeading.setTextSize(16);
    } else if (metrics.scaledDensity >= 2) {
        mHeading.setTextSize(16);
    } else if (metrics.scaledDensity >= 1 && metrics.scaledDensity < 2) {
        mHeading.setTextSize(18 / metrics.scaledDensity);
    }
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf");
    mHeading.setTypeface(tf);
    Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/arial.ttf");
    mBack.setTypeface(tf2);
    mBack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.events_back);
    mRprgmname = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

    if (Utills.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {

        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    mBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    mHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LanguagesGetAsnchTask task = new LanguagesGetAsnchTask(
                    mContext, Constants.LANGUAGE_URL);
            task.execute();
        }
    });
    mFm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
    RadioAsynchTask   
     task=newRadioAsynchTask(mContext,Constants.channels,Constants.LANGUAGE_URL, langid,
                    mRprgmname);
            task.execute();
        }
    });
    mInitialRequestResponseDto = (InitialRequestResponseDto) getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra("events");
    adapter = new EventsAdapter(this, 1, mInitialRequestResponseDto
            .getInitialResposeBean().getEvevtsdto());
    mListview.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListview.invalidate();
    mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            String title = mInitialRequestResponseDto
                .getInitialResposeBean().getEvevtsdto().get(pos)
                    .getEvent_title();
            String image = mInitialRequestResponseDto


                      .getInitialResposeBean().getEvevtsdto().get(pos)
                    .getEvent_poster();
            String desc = mInitialRequestResponseDto

                          .getInitialResposeBean().getEvevtsdto().get(pos)
                    .getLong_desc();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailedEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_path", image);
            intent.putExtra("languageid", langid);
            intent.putExtra("description", desc);
            intent.putExtra("eventtitle", title);
            intent.putExtra("name", mRprgmname);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

private void updateUi(Intent serviceIntent) {
    if (songEnded == 1) {
        mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        updateUI();
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent serviceIntent) {
        EventsActivity.this.serIntent = serviceIntent;
        if (serviceIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                MusicService.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            updateUI();
        }
        if (serviceIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
            updateUi(serviceIntent);
        }

        if (serviceIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                MusicService.BROADCAST_BUFFER)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Buffering",   
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

};

private void updateUI() {

    RadioDto songItem = MusicHolder.getInstance().getCurrentItem();
    State mState = MusicHolder.getInstance().getState();
    if (mState == State.Playing) {
        mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    } else if (mState == State.Paused || mState == State.Stopped) {
        mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

    }

    if (songItem != null) {
        title.setSelected(true);
        title.setText(songItem.getTitle());
        title.setTypeface(tf2);
        title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(234, 183, 51));
        if (AMP.isAlbumname()) {
            mPrgmTxtVw.setText("Album Name:");
        } else {
            mPrgmTxtVw.setText("Program Name:");
        }
        if (mRprgmname != null) {
            mPrgmName.setText(mRprgmname);
        } else {
            mPrgmName.setText(" ");
        }
        mPrgmName.setSelected(true);
        mPrgmName.setTypeface(tf2);
        mPrgmTxtVw.setTypeface(tf2);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics();
        if (metrics.scaledDensity < 1) {
            title.setTextSize(16);
            mPrgmTxtVw.setTextSize(14);
            mPrgmName.setTextSize(14);
        } else if (metrics.scaledDensity >= 2) {
            title.setTextSize(16);
            mPrgmTxtVw.setTextSize(14);
            mPrgmName.setTextSize(14);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mrelative
                    .getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 90); // left, top, right, bottom
            mrelative.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else if (metrics.scaledDensity >= 1 && metrics.scaledDensity < 2)    
            {
            title.setTextSize(18 / metrics.scaledDensity);
            mPrgmName.setTextSize(16 / metrics.scaledDensity);
            mPrgmTxtVw.setTextSize(16 / metrics.scaledDensity);
        }
        if (songItem.getImage() != null) {
            final String url = songItem.getImage();
            songIcon.setTag(url);
            Thread Moviesthread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                Bitmap bitmap = Utills.getBitmapFromURL(url);
                    bitmap = Utills.getCircularBitmap(bitmap);
                        songIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Moviesthread3.start();
            songIcon.invalidate();
        }

    } else {
        title.setText("Radio Khushi");
        // descrip.setText("select song from playlist");
    }
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean dia = false;
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            MusicService.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            MusicService.BROADCAST_BUFFER));

    mBroadcastIsRegistered = true;

    if (songEnded == 1) {
        mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    updateUI();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mBroadcastIsRegistered) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            mBroadcastIsRegistered = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),

                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

public void onClick(View target) {
    MusicHolder musicHolder = MusicHolder.getInstance();
    final State mState = musicHolder.getState();
    if (musicHolder.getItems().size() != 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);

        if (target == mPlayButton) {
            if (mState == State.Playing && mState != State.Preparing
                    && mState != State.Retrieving) {
                intent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_PAUSE);
                startService(intent);
        } else if (mState == State.Paused || mState == State.Stopped) {
                intent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY);
                startService(intent);
            }
        } else if (target == mNextButton) {

            intent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_SKIP);
            mNextButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next_pressed);

            startService(intent);
            String time = "";
            int index = musicHolder.getIndex();
        InitialRequestResponseDto mInitialRequestResponseDto1 = null;

            InitialResposeBean ini = new InitialResposeBean();
            ini.setRadiolist(musicHolder.getItems());
        mInitialRequestResponseDto1 = new InitialRequestResponseDto();
            mInitialRequestResponseDto1.setInitialResposeBean(ini);
            index++;
            if (index == mInitialRequestResponseDto1
                .getInitialResposeBean().getRadiolist().size()) {
                index = 0;
            }
            time = mInitialRequestResponseDto1.getInitialResposeBean()
                    .getRadiolist().get(index).getTime_zone();
            String[] s = time.split(" ");
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + s[0] + s[1]);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
            String caltime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "."
                    + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            mRprgmname = Utills.getpname1(mInitialRequestResponseDto1,
                    index, caltime, Utills.getdayofweek());

        } else if (target == mPreviousButton) {
            intent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_REWIND);
        mPreviousButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.prev_pressed);

            startService(intent);
            String time = "";
        InitialRequestResponseDto mInitialRequestResponseDto1 = null;
            int index = musicHolder.getIndex();

            InitialResposeBean ini = new InitialResposeBean();
            ini.setRadiolist(musicHolder.getItems());
        mInitialRequestResponseDto1 = new InitialRequestResponseDto();
            mInitialRequestResponseDto1.setInitialResposeBean(ini);

            index--;
            if (index == -1) {
            index = mInitialRequestResponseDto1.getInitialResposeBean()
                        .getRadiolist().size() - 1;
            }
            time = mInitialRequestResponseDto1.getInitialResposeBean()
                    .getRadiolist().get(index).getTime_zone();

            String[] s = time.split(" ");
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + s[0] + s[1]);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

            String caltime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "."
                    + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            mRprgmname = Utills.getpname1(mInitialRequestResponseDto1,
                    index, caltime, Utills.getdayofweek());
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Song In Holder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    if (mState == State.Stopped) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Song In Holder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "events ondestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mrelative=null;mPrgmName=null;mPrgmTxtVw=null;
    mBack=null;
    tf=null;
    tf2=null;
    mArrow=null;
    mFm=null;
    mHome=null;
    mRelativeLayout=null;
    mHeading=null;
    lazyImageLoader=null;
    mdialog=null;
    intent=null;
    serIntent=null;
    songIcon=null;
    title=null;
    descrip=null;
    mPreviousButton=null;
    mNextButton=null;
    mPlayButton=null;
    mContext=null;
    mInitialRequestResponseDto=null;
    adapter=null;
    mListview=null;
    System.gc();
}
```

}

and the adapter class is

```
 package com.onlineradio.adapters;

 import java.util.List;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.onlineradio.Utils.LazyImageLoader;
 import com.onlineradio.dto.EventsDto;
 import com.siriinnovations.radiokhushi.R;

 public class EventsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EventsDto> {
Context mContext;
EventsDto category;
public LazyImageLoader lazyImageLoader;
List<EventsDto> categories;
int selectedLanguage;

public EventsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<EventsDto> list) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
    this.categories = list;
    this.mContext = context;
    lazyImageLoader = new LazyImageLoader(mContext.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return categories.size();
}

public EventsDto getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView mEvntName;
    public ImageView mImage;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    category = getItem(position);
    // if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_row, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.mEvntName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.eventname);
    holder.mImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.eventimage);
    vi.setTag(holder);
    // } else {
    // holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    // }
    String title = categories.get(position).getEvent_title();
    holder.mEvntName.setText(title);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
            "fonts/arial.ttf");
    holder.mEvntName.setTypeface(tf);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    // holder.mEvntName.setTextSize(15 / metrics.scaledDensity);
    if (metrics.scaledDensity < 1) {
        holder.mEvntName.setTextSize(16);
    } else if (metrics.scaledDensity >= 2) {
        holder.mEvntName.setTextSize(14);
    } else if (metrics.scaledDensity >= 1 && metrics.scaledDensity < 2) {
        holder.mEvntName.setTextSize(18 / metrics.scaledDensity);
    }
    String imageurl = categories.get(position).getEvent_poster();
    // holder.mImage.setImageBitmap(Utills.getBitmapFromURL(imageurl));
    // new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.eventimage))
    // .execute(imageurl);

    // if ((imageurl == null) || imageurl.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
    // holder.mImage.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    //
    // } else {
    lazyImageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, holder.mImage,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // holder.mImage.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    // WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATC`enter code here`H_PARENT,
    // WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // holder.mImage.setImageBitmap(Utills.getBitmapFromURL(imageurl));
    holder.mImage.setTag(imageurl);
    // holder.mImage.invalidate();
    return vi;
}

 }
```

Comment: its the job of garbage collector to free memory. and you are updating ui in a thread  `songIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Comment: Are you actually running out of memory? The GC runs when it runs, and it's perfectly free to not clear out unused objects until you actually need the memory.

Comment: I have seen my ddms heap on this but it not deallocating the memory and my activity is closing when i am repeatingly open this activity and it is reopening the previous activity i think it is the problem of low memory

Answer (score 0):

Use MAT to analyze your app's memory usage, as discussed in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) post. This tool will help you track the memory used by the app and discover potential memory leaks.

Comment: I have seen my ddms MAT heap on this but it not deallocating the memory and my activity is closing when i am repeatingly open this activity and it is reopening the previous activity i think it is the problem of low memory

Comment: @prakash - You have to use MAT to >>analyse<< the heap usage.  Just looking at it and observing that the memory is not being released is missing the point.  You need to use MAT's ability to figure out what memory is leaking, and why.

Comment: @Stephen - I have seen the posted link and i didn't understand anything how to free the memory i used HPROF to dump the heap in onlowmemory event but it does nothing for me. Plz help me on this..

Comment: @prakash 1) Have you read the linked articles?  2) Have you searched for other articles on MAT and Android memory leak trouble-shooting using Google search and StackOverflow search?  3) If yes to both, then please explain what you don't understand about the articles that you have read ... specifically?  Just saying "I don't understand" does not help us help you.

Comment: @prakash - And no, I am NOT going to try to find the leak for you.  For free.